# Neo4j javascript example error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7687/' failed: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am trying to make the example neo4j javascript project run in my work machine. npm install completed fine and I am able to run the webpack dev using npm run dev.

When I navigate to the test page, http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server, the page renders fine but does not connect to the running Neo4j instance. There are no passwords, etc in the file. The error message is:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7687/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 in the neo4j-server.conf and 
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687 in neo4j.conf

Neo4j version: 2.3.8

Please advise if some other settings are needed.

**Note**: This project works fine in a less-locked machine so it is an issue with local security settings

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** The issue was resolved by switching to the latest version of Neo4j - it appears anything above 3.0.1 works fine. The BOLT drivers/connection protocols may have changed.

To summarize, the [**BOLT JavaScript Neo4j example project**](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-javascript-bolt) works only with Neo4j 3.0.1 and higher.

Comment: Makes sense, I think BOLT was only added in 3.0.x, it definitely didn't exist in 2.3.8.